# How do I calculate the position of a vehicle moving between tiles, over time?

Tags: movement, tilemap, interpolation

I'm working on a small multiplayer game where players can create cities, and these cities will be placed on what's called the "world map." The world map is basically a giant coordinate plane made up of tiles, and the server will load the "world map" in chunks from the database relative to a player's position on the world map.

Now, I want players to be able to send planes from their city to another spot/tile anywhere on the world map. Say for instance player who owns **City 1** at position **10,10**, wants to create an **oil_well** at position **70,30**. I want a plane to fly from the departure point to arrival point, and client that loads the chunk will see that plane flying across the map.

*How can I make the server calculate where the plane is?* I have the following information:

`departure_time`, `origin_x`, `origin_y`, `arrival_x`, `arrival_y`, `speed`. `speed` is the time in seconds that a plane can cross a tile on the world map.

I also have `distance`, which is simply calculated as (distance formula):

```
var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow( data.arrival_x - data.origin_x , 2) + Math.pow( data.arrival_y - data.origin_y , 2));
```

Again, how can I calculate the current position of a moving plane on this world map? Because the plane can fly at many different angles, depending on the angle of **departure point → arrival point**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Scalar multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_multiplication).

Assuming the plane moves at constant speed, you can determine how far along it is (0 meaning at `departure_point` and 1 meaning at `arrival_point`)

```
progress = distance / speed * time_elapsed
```

You can also compute a vector *(x,y)* representing the translation of the airplane from its departure point to its arrival point, by subtracting one position from the other.

```
x = arrival_x - departure_x
y = arrival_y - departure_y
```

[image: translation vector]

Then simply multiply that translation vector `x`,`y` by the proportion of `progress` that has been made.

```
moved_by_x = x * progress
moved_by_y = y * progress
```

You can then add that vector to the departure point to find the point where the plane should be.

```
plane_x = departure_x + moved_by_x
plane_y = departure_y + moved_by_y
```

[image: 0.0] [image: 0.2] [image: 0.5] [image: 0.9]

<sup>**departure point** red, **arrival point** blue, **plane position** orange</sup>

Comment: Perfect! I was outside trying to wrap my head around this problem, and actually thought about addressing the problem in some fashion similar to this. Thanks!

Comment: @josh Happy if it helped. :)