# How do I set an object's speed to arrive in X seconds?

Tags: physics, libgdx, movement, timing

I want to move an object to a point in the game world, I have the distance value which is far the player should move. I want to complete the movement in X seconds.

I have tried many equations and formulas to no success.

```
Speed = Distance/Time
```

This one doesn't seem to give me the right result. Thing is the game is updated 60 times a second and the movement is affected by delta time.

I'm pretty sure I am not taking the framerate in consideration.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit:

This is how I calculate the speed:

```
int dst = 500;
int time = 2; // in seconds
float speed = dst / time;
```

Doing it this way is making the movement instant and the game object is not traveling the distance in 2 seconds.

Every frame each game objects gets updated this way:

```
p.x += dir.x * speed * deltaTime;
p.y += dir.y * speed * deltaTime;
```

The dir vector holds the direction of movement which is calculated on mouse click:

```
Vector2 dir = new Vector2(mouseX, mouseY).subtract(objectX, objectY).normalize();
```

Delta time calculation:

```
long time = System.nanoTime();
float deltaTime = (time - lastTime) / 1000000000.0f;
lastTime = time;
```

Please note: The game object stops upon arrival.

Comment: [This question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/105273/7804) sounds very similar. Is it what you mean?

Comment: When you multiply your speed by elapsed time each update (ignoring fps), what behavior do you see?  The approach you describe seems correct.

Comment: @Anko I think so, I am trying to calculate in what speed the object will move so it will travel the distance in X seconds.

Comment: @StevenHansen I have made an edit. Maybe you can help me now?

Comment: Is `deltaTime` a variable time step? (I mean, possibly a different value frame-to-frame?) [Arguments against variable time steps for physics here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/when-should-i-use-a-fixed-or-variable-time-step).

Comment: @Anko Yes, it can change between frames but the change is slight.

Comment: Perhaps you need to post more code.  How did you compute `deltaTime`?  What is `dir` and how did you compute it?  In your sample, `speed` is a vector, but you declared it as a float.  As is, your question is insufficiently clear.

Comment: Excuse me for not being clear. I have updated the code. I am using libgdx if this can help, and my FPS is locked on 60 (although I might change it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are specifying a time in seconds as an integer value, but you are not taking into account the game's frames per second.

If your game was running at 1 frame per second, it would work, because after two frames (thus, two seconds), your object would have travelled the specified distance.

It's a simple case of multiplying your time by your FPS:

```
int dst = 500;
float time = 2 * Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond(); // in seconds
float speed = dst / time;
```

If your game is running at 60 FPS, the speed of the object would be `500 / 120`, or `4.16`.

Additionally, as you are using libGDX, your calculation of deltaTime is irrelevant as it is already provided:

```
float deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
```

Comment: Thank you! I have specified the calculation from the source for the sake of good order.